# In MongoDB how to know if it is the last record of a collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

How to know if I'm returning the **last** set of document/documents of a collection?

For now I keep the full document count as reference to check if I received the all the records.

I'm using **skip** with **limit** for lazy loading. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: It is the correct way. you don't even need to keep track of count. just keep calling with limit and skip till there are no elements

Comment: @AbhishekAnand was aware of that. But in some APIs I have seen there is a variable if it is the last record. Like isLastRecord: true;

Answer (score 0):

You can, as confirmed by @Abhishek Anand

- count +
- skip,limit

You can also fetch limit+1 documents, and only return `min(n documents found, limit)`
This way you avoid a count, and you know you reached the end of collection whenever you don't have `limit+1 documents found`

Comment: thanks for the answer. But not what I'm looking for

Comment: Then I am not sure to understand what you are expecting. In above you know when you have reached the end of the collection. But since it is not what you expect maybe can you precise or edit your post to give an example?

Comment: I have just read your comment on the original post. Do you mean how from the API to indicate to the consumer if he has to make another fetch or not?